# Difference between Re-entrant and Thread-Safe function

Tags: c, multithreading

What is the difference between a re-entrant function and a thread safe function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274254/what-kind-of-code-can-be-called-re-entrant/2274289#2274289

Comment: very similar if not identical:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856823/threadsafe-vs-re-entrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the [wiki article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_(subroutine)#Relation_to_thread_safety). It explains it well so please see that for a full discussion.

A few relevant bits from the article:

> In computing, a computer program or subroutine is called reentrant if it can be interrupted in the middle of its execution, and then be safely called again ("re-entered") before its previous invocations complete execution. The interruption could be caused by an internal action such as a jump or call, or by an external action such as a hardware interrupt or signal. Once the reentered invocation completes, the previous invocations will resume correct execution.

and

> This definition of reentrancy differs from that of thread-safety in multi-threaded environments. A reentrant subroutine can achieve thread-safety, but being reentrant alone might not be sufficient to be thread-safe in all situations. Conversely, thread-safe code does not necessarily have to be reentrant (see below for examples).

Comment: Please post an actual answer that summarizes the link in case it goes cold (as is the case here and now).

Answer (score 2):

Re-entrant means no global state (local only).

Thread safe means it is not possible for 2 (or more) threads to conflict with each other (by writing conflicting values).

Answer (score 2):

> - A *thread-safe function* can be called simultaneously from multiple
>   threads, even when the invocations use shared data, because all
>   references to the shared data are serialized.
> - A *reentrant function* can
>   also be called simultaneously from multiple threads, but only if each
>   invocation uses its own data.
>
> Hence, a thread-safe function is always reentrant, but a reentrant
> function is not always thread-safe.

The difference can be cottoned on with the example,

> A class is said to be reentrant if its member functions can be called
> safely from multiple threads, as long as each thread uses a different
> instance of the class. The class is thread-safe if its member
> functions can be called safely from multiple threads, even if all the
> threads use the same instance of the class.

Source: [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html)